# Is there an int.INFINITY for Dart?

Tags: dart

I see there is a double.INFINITY but I can't see a way to say "int INFINITY". Which is interesting, because I see I can do `some_integer.isInfinite`.

What's a way to say `int.INFINITY` in Dart? Does that even make sense?

Comment: what'd be the point? ints have fixed sizes they can't go past. allowing them to represent something outside their range would be rather counter-productive.

Comment: @MarcB Ints in Dart don't have a fixed size. They are only "Limited by RAM" https://www.dartlang.org/articles/numeric-computation/

Comment: I'm guessing that since the `isInfinite` method is inherited from `num`, and `int`s can be as big as RAM allows, it will always return `false` when called on an `int`.  In other words, there is no "integer infinity" in Dart, and the method is only there because it gets inherited from `num`.

Comment: In Web applications, Dart's `int` inherits from `double` and it can be infinity as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. All Dart integers are finite.
You can ask `42.isInfinite`, but the answer is predictably `false`. If you check the code of the `int` class, you'll like find `bool get isInfinite => false;` somewhere.

The reason the getter is there at all is that it's defined on `num`, the superclass of `int` and `double`, and you can do many operation on numbers without knowing whether they are integers or doubles.

Comment: Thanks! Should we update the dartdocs for int.isInfinite to say "always returns false" ? Right now, it says "True if the number is positive infinity or negative infinity; otherwise, false."

Comment: We could add something along the lines of "All integers are finite, only double has infinite values." as elaboration.